# Set custom reponse header in spring from within PermissionEvaluator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I have a custom permission class like below, which I use for method security with @PreAuthorize, it works fine, but I need to add custom response headers based on some business logic from within this class, If someone could throw some light in this area, it would be of great help.

> > on controller
>
> @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('APP', 'GENERIC', 'VIEW')")

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = 
          new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
  public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
        boolean dev = true;

        public CustomPermissionEvaluator() {

        }

        public void init() {

        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(
          Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
            System.out.println("CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission()-X");
            if ((auth == null) || (targetDomainObject == null) || !(permission instanceof String)){
                return false;
            }
            String targetType = targetDomainObject.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();

            return hasPrivilege(auth, "X",targetType, permission.toString().toUpperCase());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(
          Authentication auth, Serializable category, String module, Object permission) {
            String cat = (String) category;
            System.out.println("CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission()-Y "+module);
            if ((auth == null) || StringUtils.isEmpty(module) || !(permission instanceof String)) { 
                return false;
            }
            return hasPrivilege(auth, cat,module.toUpperCase(), permission.toString().toUpperCase());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, it's simple, you can't call other methods than "hasPermission(...)" returning a boolean on a "PermissionEvaluator", and generating response header is the responsability of a controller class. So if you have common logic between your PermissionEvaluator and a controller, just put the logic in a common dependency.

Comment: Or if i am able to pull those haspermission method param values in some filter that would also suffice. Is it posisble to retrieve that values in a filter?

Comment: I think you should show us how you call these "hasPermission(...)" methods.

Comment: Ok, modified my question, added another class from where evaluator is being called and the annotation as well which is used in controller

Answer (score 0):

This could help someone in near future, I was able to achieve it in this way.

```
HttpServletResponse resp  = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getResponse();
        resp.setHeader("TEST", "TEST");
```